# Liferay Import Guest layouts from a larFile Programatically

Tags: liferay

I am trying to import some guest layouts from a larFile(exported from another instance) in to a liferay instance (can be an already installed_and_configured OR can be a fresh installation) by creating a class which extends SimpleAction in a Start up Hook ( ) and then pointing 'application.startup.events' to this class in the portal-ext.properties file. I want this to run every time the server starts as my larFile version may change over the time. My Code is as follows...

```
File larFile=new File("/Users/grai001/Desktop/default_guest_public_new_light.lar");

//using absolute path for now -need help in accessing the relative path to ${liferay.home}??

Group guestGroup = GroupLocalServiceUtil.getGroup(1, GroupConstants.GUEST);
LayoutLocalServiceUtil.importLayouts(guestGroup.getCreatorUserId(), guestGroup.getGroupId(), false, new HashMap<String,String[]>(), larFile);

//I want them to be a public layouts which are visible to every one even when a user is not logged in - like the default WHAT-WE-DO kind ofpages in liferay6.1 - I am using 6.1GA2 at both ends
```

How ever this is giving me null pointer exception and the stack trace is as below..

```
com.liferay.portal.kernel.exception.SystemException: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.liferay.portal.service.impl.LayoutLocalServiceImpl.importLayouts(LayoutLocalServiceImpl.java:1398)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:122)
at com.liferay.portal.service.impl.LayoutLocalServiceVirtualLayoutsAdvice.invoke(LayoutLocalServiceVirtualLayoutsAdvice.java:197)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:118)
at com.liferay.portal.service.impl.LayoutLocalServiceStagingAdvice.invoke(LayoutLocalServiceStagingAdvice.java:107)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:118)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.transaction.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:71)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:118)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:57)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:118)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:57)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:118)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:57)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:118)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:57)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:118)
at com.liferay.portal.security.pacl.PACLAdvice.invoke(PACLAdvice.java:51)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:118)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanAopProxy.invoke(ServiceBeanAopProxy.java:211)
at $Proxy27.importLayouts(Unknown Source)
at com.liferay.portal.service.LayoutLocalServiceUtil.importLayouts(LayoutLocalServiceUtil.java:1037)
at com.walmart.services.mpportal.liferay.startup.StartupHook.run(StartupHook.java:88)
at com.liferay.portal.events.EventsProcessorImpl.processEvent(EventsProcessorImpl.java:106)
at com.liferay.portal.events.EventsProcessorImpl.process(EventsProcessorImpl.java:58)
at com.liferay.portal.events.EventsProcessorUtil.process(EventsProcessorUtil.java:53)
at com.liferay.portal.util.PortalInstances._initCompany(PortalInstances.java:462)
at com.liferay.portal.util.PortalInstances.initCompany(PortalInstances.java:92)
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.initCompanies(MainServlet.java:798)
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.init(MainServlet.java:355)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1266)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1185)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1080)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5015)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5302)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:895)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:871)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:615)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:649)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1585)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.ParamUtil.getLong(ParamUtil.java:616)
at com.liferay.portal.service.impl.LayoutLocalServiceStagingAdvice.deleteLayout(LayoutLocalServiceStagingAdvice.java:70)
at com.liferay.portal.service.impl.LayoutLocalServiceStagingAdvice.invoke(LayoutLocalServiceStagingAdvice.java:113)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:118)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.transaction.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:71)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:118)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:57)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:118)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:57)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:118)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:57)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:118)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:57)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:118)
at com.liferay.portal.security.pacl.PACLAdvice.invoke(PACLAdvice.java:51)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:118)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanAopProxy.invoke(ServiceBeanAopProxy.java:211)
at $Proxy27.deleteLayout(Unknown Source)
at com.liferay.portal.service.LayoutLocalServiceUtil.deleteLayout(LayoutLocalServiceUtil.java:435)
at com.liferay.portal.lar.LayoutImporter.deleteMissingLayouts(LayoutImporter.java:196)
at com.liferay.portal.lar.LayoutImporter.doImportLayouts(LayoutImporter.java:774)
at com.liferay.portal.lar.LayoutImporter.importLayouts(LayoutImporter.java:147)
at com.liferay.portal.service.impl.LayoutLocalServiceImpl.importLayouts(LayoutLocalServiceImpl.java:1382)
... 50 more
```

And now doing `LayoutLocalServiceUtil.importLayouts(guestGroup.getCreatorUserId(), guestGroup.getGroupId(), true, new HashMap<String,String[]>(), larFile);` 
**ie...importing them as private layouts is working fine - unfortunately I want them to be public and be visible to every one. Also logging in as portal adminstrator and 
importing from the UI as public layouts is working well and good. How ever I want this to be done in an automated way**.

Trying to solve this problem of mine from the past 1 week - did enough research - but still couldn't. Any kind of help is appreciated..!

Thanks in advance

Comment: You might want to either inspect the root-cause stacktrace (as it will give away the actual NullpointerException location) or debug into this process. If you have a hook, you most likely can run it in a debugger - add Liferay sourcecode to it and as soon as you hit the import routine (breakpoint) set an exception breakpoint on NullpointerException. This will give you some ideas where else to look.

Comment: you will have to debug the NullPonterException as suggested by Olaf Kock. In LayoutLocalServiceUtil.importLayouts(guestGroup.getCreatorUserId(), guestGroup.getGroupId(), true, new HashMap<String,String[]>(), larFile); pass the third parameter as false to import into public.

Comment: was finally able to remote debug it few days back. problem is with some parameters (don't remember them exactly) I am passing with paramsMap.

Comment: Have you found a solution? I have the similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void larTest()  {

    LiferayFacesContext liferayFacesContext = LiferayFacesContext
            .getInstance();
    ActionRequest request = (ActionRequest) liferayFacesContext
            .getPortletRequest();
    ThemeDisplay td = (ThemeDisplay) request
            .getAttribute(WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY);
    long userId = td.getUserId();
    long groupId = td.getScopeGroupId();

    File larFile=new File("C:\\Users\\youssef\\dahar\\Downloads\\ok.lar");

    //using absolute path for now -need help in accessing the relative path to ${liferay.home}??

    Group guestGroup = null;
    try {
        guestGroup = GroupLocalServiceUtil.getGroup(groupId);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("catch 1");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        LayoutLocalServiceUtil.importLayouts(guestGroup.getCreatorUserId(), guestGroup.getGroupId(), false, new HashMap<String,String[]>(), larFile);
    } catch (PortalException e) {
        System.out.println("catch 2");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SystemException e) {
        System.out.println("catch 3");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //I want them to be a public layouts which are visible to every one even when a user is not logged in - like the default WHAT-WE-DO kind ofpages in liferay6.1 - I am using 6.1GA2 at both ends


}
```

may be can help you this function
it worked for me sometimes and sometimes no :)